# Different Controllers for backend and frontend

Tags: php, laravel

So this past year I have dived into professional web development using laravel, and the journey has been amazing, with stackoverflow helping me tremendously. This question is more of an opinion rather than me asking how to do it. So, I'll break it down with an example.
Suppose I am creating an articles website. For the articles, I create a migration, model, controller and then views. For migration and model, it only requires one set of it because only one table exists for it. For views I have separate folders for admin panel for backend and frontend. Usually in the routes I'll create a group for backend with prefix of admin and auth guard which comes built in with laravel, though in the newer versions of laravel you gotta do composer require laravel/ui. Now, because I have different routes for both backend and frontend, logically what I do is create a completely different Controller for the backend with all the CRUD functionality, and for the frontend I make a separate controller and put index and show function in it. 
Is this the best way to deal with it, or is there a more efficient way of handling the backend and the frontend? Also, is the basic workflow of development usually the same as I have mentioned, or do you people have a different take on how to do these things. Please let me know. 
Cheers :)

Comment: This seems to me more of a permission problem rather than a architecture issue. Overall you should not care what controller does what but rather who does the action. If it easier for you to separate the front from the back then by all means have at it.

Comment: Exactly. I mean when returning a response, usually in laravel we return the view with the variable. Now having separate views for backend and frontend, this creates problem having a single function dealing with two different outputs, which in my limited programming knowledge seems impossible.

Comment: Using MVC architecture you are indeed covering most of the issues of the frontend-backend... But with your question, I'm undestanding that; maybe are you confusing backend with admin panel?

Comment: Maybe in regards to this particular example, I am referring to the admin panel. But generally, because where I work I am the sole developer there, I deal with both backend and frontend stuff on my own. So the logic here is of double nature, firstly should an admin panel have a separate controller, and also should backend development, lets say API development should also be completely separate from what happens in the application itself?

Comment: Lets say I create an api controller separately and then call it somehow in both the frontend and the admin panel. or should both the logic of it be separate and mixed with the entire development together with numerous controllers to handle the logic

Comment: I would use different controllers myself, just makes for a more granular and encapsulated system, particularly as in most cases the front end and back end have very different purposes and functions

Comment: You are making the mistake of considering the **database as the central point of your application**. Unfortunately, this kind of thinking is somehow enforced by Laravel through the use of its Eloquent ORM and active record pattern. As a consequence, you are trying to find and apply commonalities in the design of your application. E.g. you are presuming that the _admin panel_ and the _frontend_ - since they are sharing the same persistence space - have enough functionalities in common to develop them under the roof of the same application.

Comment: Though - making abstraction of Laravel - if you'd **think in terms of business logic**, you'd discover that the two "modules" have not much in common. And, if you'd consider to adopt an [ubiquitous language](https://www.agilealliance.org/glossary/ubiquitous-language/) when designing the domain model of each of them, you'd probably discover (a lot) more differences.

Comment: More of it, considering that different components are used to model the business logic of the modules, then different access methods to these components would have to be used. E.g. - in Laravel - different _controllers_ and _routes_. As for the _views_, they are, of course, different. So, I would suggest to develop the _admin panel_ and the _frontend_ as two different applications.

Comment: Here are some resources for understanding the main principles behind building a good MVC-based application: [Keynote: Architecture the Lost Years](https://confreaks.tv/videos/rubymidwest2011-keynote-architecture-the-lost-years), [Sandro Mancuso : Crafted Design](https://vimeo.com/107963074).

Answer (score 1):

In most projects, frontend and backend, are two different environments with different needs, so using the same controllers would be inappropriate as it might lead in complex - no-clean code.

What works for me best, is to separate the controllers in the following groups:

- Frontend
- Backend
- API

In some cases you might also need a group for the controllers handling the ajax/async requests, i.e. Async group.